# error in double while using % operator

Tags: c++

I am working on a question which asks to create a class `Rational`, with variables as numerator and denominator, and a function to add two rational numbers.

This is the class I created:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    // n stands for numerator and d stands for denominator
    double n,d;
    // add stands for addition
    void add(Rational r1, Rational r2);
};
```

And this is my function:

```
void Rational::add(Rational r1, Rational r2)
{
    // ar stands for rational number after addition
    double ar;
    // new object which takes the value after addition
    Rational r3;
    // formula for numerator after addition
    r3.n=(r1.n*r2.d)+(r2.n*r1.d);
    // formula for denominator after addition
    r3.d=(r1.d*r2.d);
    // ratio equals divisor plus quotient multiplied to remainder
    ar=(r3.n/r3.d)+((r3.n)%(r3.d))*r3.d;
}
```

The last line generates the following error during compilation:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'|
```

I am new to cpp and this my homework... Please help...

Comment: You really didn't need all of that code to demonstrate the problem you're having.  [See this](http://ideone.com/YdNM6q).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Context matters. Your attempted minimal demonstration fails to include the most significant aspects.

Comment: Please clarify whether the assignment required you to use `double`, or that was your decision. Normally "rational number" means that the numerator and denominator are integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(r3.n)%(r3.d)
```

`n` and `d` are of type `double`. Operator `%` (modulo) is only available for integers.

As @Cheers and hth. - Alf kindly pointed in the comments, the best solution would be to declare `n` and `d` as integers, since it will be more coherent to represent a rational number.

If you can't do that and really have a reason to use doubles, you will have to use [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead:

```
std::fmod(r3.n, r3.d)
```

Comment: **−1** “Use `std::fmod` instead” is negative value advice.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ `%` is only available for integers.

Use an integer type for `n` and `d`.

This also helps ensure that the *values* are mathematical integers, which you're not guaranteed with a floating point type.

Answer (score 0):

As `%` is only for integers, therefore you will have to use `fmod(x,y)`. You will also have to add `#include <math.h>` as header.

Comment: `math.h` is a C header ;)

Comment: **−1** “you will have to use `fmod(x,y)`” is negative value advice.

Comment: What is the positive value advice then?